# Creating SEO URLs with slug and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to create SEO URLs with PHP MySQL and .htaccess.

Here is my PHP code:

```
echo '<li>'.$icon.' <a href=\'software.php?pid='.softid.''.$slug.'\'>'.$title.'</a></li>';
```

The URL will be `base_url/software-name-etc`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /filemono-v2
RewriteRule ^software-profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_]-)/([0-9]+)\.php$ software-profile.php?pid=$1
</IfModule>
```

What’s wrong with my code? I’m getting a 404.

Comment: You're rewriting to a directory where your PHP file does not reside. Take out the RewriteBase line and it should come to life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu need to change your php code to reflect what your rewrite rule is matching against:

```
echo '<li>'.$icon.' <a href=\'/software-profile/'.$softid.'/'.$slug.'.php\'>'.$title.'</a></li>';
```

So the anchor should look like `/software-profile/pid/slug.php`

Comment: no its notworking i think i have problem in .htaccess as well